# How to retrieve a document by its own sub document or array?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have such structure of document:

```
{  
    "_id" : "4e76fd1e927e1c9127d1d2e8",  
    "name" : "***",  
    "embedPhoneList" : [  
        {  
            "type" : "家庭",  
            "number" : "00000000000"  
        },  
        {  
            "type" : "手机",  
            "number" : "00000000000"  
        }  
    ],  
    "embedAddrList" : [  
        {  
            "type" : "家庭",  
            "addr" : "山东省诸城市***"  
        },  
        {  
            "type" : "工作",  
            "addr" : "深圳市南山区***"  
        }  
    ],  
    "embedEmailList" : [  
        {  
            "email" : "********@gmail.com"  
        },  
        {  
            "email" : "********@gmail.com"  
        },  
        {  
            "email" : "********@gmail.com"  
        },  
        {  
            "email" : "********@gmail.com"  
        }  
    ]  
}
```

What I wan't to do is find the document by it's sub document,such as `email` in `embedEmailList` field.
Or if I have structure like this

```
{  
    "_id" : "4e76fd1e927e1c9127d1d2e8",  
    "name" : "***",   
    "embedEmailList" : [  
        "123@gmail.com" ,  
        "********@gmail.com" ,  
        ]  
}
```

the `embedEmailList` is array,how to find if there is `123@gmail.com`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for a specific value in an array, mongodb supports this syntax:

```
db.your_collection.find({embedEmailList : "foo@bar.com"});
```

See [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ValueinanArray) for more information.

To search for a value in an embedded object, it supports this syntax:

```
db.your_collection.find({"embedEmailList.email" : "foo@bar.com"});
```

See [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ValueinanEmbeddedObject) for more information.